# read multiple files into r, no column names

Tags: r, filenames, rbind

I have a number of .txt files, with the data comma separated. There are no headers. Each contains the same information, but by different years: the name, the gender and the number of names.

I can read them all in in one `rbind` okay, but I lose the year information - the year is contained only in the file name... `y1920.txt`, `y1995.txt`, `y2002.txt` and so on.

I am very new to R.

To `rbind` them, I used `do.call(file, rbind)`, where file is the list of `data.frame`s.

Answer (score 2):

Plyr has a nice workflow for this, assuming your files are all in the current working directory:

```
library(plyr)
years <- ldply(list.files(pattern="y\\d{4}\\.txt"), 
               function(file){ 
                 data <- read.csv(file, header=F); 
                 data$date <- gsub("y","",gsub("\\.txt","", file)); 
                 data})
```

If you want to specify your files instead, e.g. `files <- c("y1995.txt", "y1996.txt")`, you can replace the first argument to `ldply` (`list.files(...)`) with `files` instead.

Comment: +1 very nice. Essentially the same as a `for` loop, but skips the `rbind` section (or `rbindlist` if you are into `data.table`s)